# "Only she in the world " or "only her in the world"?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, objects

Example:

> My girlfriend acted her usual self today. She chuckled at my dumb
>   jokes, slung her cute remarks, gaped at the thoughts **only she/her in
>   the world** found interesting.

I searched both phrases on Google and they have the same number of hits. So I'm confused.

Comment: As Chris M. has demonstrated below, take out "in the world" and you will be able to see more easily which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only she found interesting

This is correct because **"she"** is the *subject pronoun* of the verb found.